# SQL Server 2005 Express other users can't see stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I added a couple of stored procedures to a SQL Server 2005 database at our company. The database uses Windows Authentication.  Other users cannot see the procedures, although they can view the database/tables/stored procedures using SQL Server Management Express.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you grant execute permissions to the SPs:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON [sp name] TO [user/role]
```